# Error "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0"

Tags: docker

I'm building a Docker Image from the Dockerfile on Windows 10. I download the Docker file from [here](https://github.com/openzim/zim-tools/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile) and put in the directory `F:\zimtools\Dockerfile`.

[image]

The content of the file is

```
ARG VERSION=
FROM alpine:3
ARG VERSION
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source https://github.com/openzim/zim-tools
RUN echo "Build image for version: $2021-04-20"

RUN wget -O - -q https://download.openzim.org/nightly/2021-04-20/zim-tools_linux-x86_64-2021-04-20.tar.gz | tar -xz && \
  cp zim-tools*/* /usr/local/bin/ && \
  rm -rf zim-tools*

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 'Welcome to zim-tools! The following binaries are available:' && ls /usr/local/bin/"]
```

I follow [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-use-dockerfiles/) instruction and run below command in cmd.

```
docker build --tag=“zimtools:nightly” "F:\zimtools\Dockerfile"
```

Then I got an error

```
C:\Users\Akira>docker build --tag="zimtools:nightly" "F:\zimtools\Dockerfile"
[+] Building 0.0s (1/2)
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 75B                                                                                0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: walk F:\zimtools\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Could you please explain how to solve this error?

**Update:** My setup is

- Docker Engine: v20.10.5
- OS: Windows 10 Pro, version 20H2, build 19042.928.

Comment: What is the docker version and your OS?

Comment: @Ashok please see my edit.

Comment: Try to purge the settings and restart

Comment: @Ashok What do you mean by "purge the settings"?

Comment: Click on this little bug icon up to the right, and then you can see the settings in that there'll be option Purge. Before doing this restart the docker service and try if not then purge the settings

Comment: @Ashok The same error persists :((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231374/discussion-between-ashok-and-le-anh-dung).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To build your docker image:

1. `cd` to your path where the `dockerfile` is (In your case it's `F:\zimtools\`)
2. `docker build .`

This is similar to this command `docker build -f Dockerfile .`

You need to specify the `Dockerfile` name only when it's not default:

1. `cd` to your path where the `dockerfile` is (In your case it's `F:\zimtools\`)
2. `docker build -f <your modified docker file> .`

Answer (score 3):

In order to prevent this error try to disable docker buildkit before running any docker related command:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
```

Now run your command:

```
docker blah blah ...
docker-compose blah blah ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. What helped me was creating another subfolder in the home directory and moving the dockerfile into that.

See [this](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/415#issuecomment-733959988)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding an explanation of the link you supplied.